# How to build a custom utop-based toplevel with ocamlbuild?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind, utop, ocaml-toplevel

I want to create a utop-based toplevel for my project, which is built by `ocamlbuild`.

However, `ocamlbuild` supports only mktoplevel, built from `*.mltop`. It doesn't mention `utop` anywhere in the docs.

Also, the `utop` manual explains just toplevel creation by `jbuilder` and doesn't even mention `ocamlbuild`. It also explains building via `ocamlfind`, but strongly discourages that approach.

So how should I create my utop-based toplevel?

Or, is this a totally wrong approach and I should do something different to get my utop-based toplevel. If so, what is the recommended way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `custom-utop` example from the utop sources used to be built with ocamlbuild and was later to jbuilder. See [this older version](https://github.com/diml/utop/tree/b37ead142aa8d9e3583103aebd1688ac65b2fee8/examples/custom-utop) for an example.